# How powerful is Saruman's Ring ( which he made himself )?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, saruman

In the books, Saruman forges a Ring and wears it along with a shimmering cloak. This is known when Saruman reveals it to Gandalf. As the title implies,  how powerful is this Ring  ?

It must be noted that Saruman is no stranger to forging. He served the Valar Aulë the Smith (whom Sauron also previously served). Hence he would have considerable expertise in making stuff. He also studied a lot about Sauron and the One Ring.

Putting all these together, how powerful is Saruman's Ring?

Comment: I can't find the necessary quotes. Can someone add them please?

Comment: Some may point out this is a duplicate, but it isn't. There are many questions about Saruman's Ring, but non about its power

Comment: Sure, but any relevant (canonical)info about the ring would end up on the dupe question...

Comment: It is never demonstrated to have any power.  Saruman refers to himself as Ring-Maker, and a ring is seen on his hand, but he does not use it.  It may have had a hidden power, but to me it always seemed like a bluff - Saruman was emulating Sauron, aspirationally, but had not actually managed to create a capital-R Ring.